# Can INSERT be used as a way to update a database instead of using UPDATE?

Tags: php, sql, insert, mysqli

I am having an issue with an update command. It's not as if the code is written wrong; I've had three people look at it and not come up with a solid answer of why the code is not working.  So in lieu of getting the code to work, is it possible to use INSERT to replace the data in the database instead of using UPDATE?

Comment: You should *really* figure out what's the problem with your update instead of trying some crazy stuff.

Comment: Your question about the update appears to offer solutions to the update problem (that the PHP syntax was incorrect).  I strongly recommend concentrating on that.

Answer (score 2):

No. Insert will only create a new row.

Well … you could perform a delete followed by an insert, but that way lies madness.

Comment: You'd have to do it the other way around, what if you delete a row and the insert fails, you've lost the data.

Comment: @RMcLeod: That's what transactions are for. :-)  *Not that I'm in any way advocating this method over just figuring out what's wrong with the UPDATE, mind you...*

Comment: Well, but you cannot do the other way if there is a primary (unique) key in table. Transaction should resolve the data-loss problem.

Comment: I figure this after many times of try to use insert in update way. Error keeps popping and I keep ignoring the difference between insert and update.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL, there's `REPLACE` that deletes possible existing row and inserts ([mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)) or, equivalaent syntax `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` ([mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)).

For some other databases, there's `MERGE` - [Oracle](http://blogs.oracle.com/cmar/entry/using_merge_to_do_an), [MS SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522.aspx)

Anyway, these are good to know of, but you'd rather fix the `UPDATE` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to insert a new row, check that has inserted row worked and then delete the original, this will cause you all sorts of problem with unique keys.

Post your code and the error you're getting someone here might be able to spot something that has been missed.

Comment: You should first delete the row, then insert the new one. You will not be able to insert the new one if the old one is still there due to PK violations.

Comment: Here is the new code, in another page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851298/update-code-causing-error-but-it-looks-fine-to-me