# UPDATE Code causing Error, but it looks fine to me:

Tags: php, mysqli

Issue 2.

I am now getting an error in where the code is not inputting the actual ID number into the query...

Here is the error:

**Query Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1**

The code has been updated to show the new code. (again) this time with a hidden script, and a few other tweaks. I've about lost hope on getting this to work.

```
Issue 1 Solved:    
This line of code is brining back and error: 

        $query = "UPDATE ncmr SET ab = '$ab', date = '$date', part = '$part', rev = '$rev' , partdesc = '$partdesc' , ncmrqty = '$ncmrqty' , comp = '$comp' , ncmrid = '$ncmrid' , rma = '$rma' , jno = '$jno' , fdt = '$fdt' , cof = '$cof' , fab1 = '$fab1' , fab2 = '$fab2' , fab3 = '$fab3' , non = '$non' , dis = '$dis' , comm = '$comm' , caad = '$caad' , po = '$po' , pod = '$pod' , dri = '$dri'  WHERE id = "$_GET['id']"";

    The error is: 

    **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/pawz/public_html/kaboomlabs.com/testbed/edit.php on line 49**

I can't figure out why it is doing it, if someone can show me my mistake it be greatlyfully appreciated.
```

Ok, here is the code in it's entirety.

```
            <?php
require_once('connectvars.php');
echo '<div id="postwrap">'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PDI NCMR - Edit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/postie.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div id="logo">
    <img src="../images/PDI_Logo_2.1.gif" alt="PDI Logo" />
</div>

<?php

      $id=0;
      if(isset($_GET['id']))
         $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['id']));

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST["id"]));
// Connect to the database
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Enter data into the database
    $ab = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ab']));
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['date']))));
    $part = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['part']));
    $rev = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rev']));
    $partdesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['partdesc']));
    $ncmrqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrqty']));
    $comp = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comp']));
    $ncmrid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrid']));
    $rma = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rma']));
    $jno = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['jno']));
    $fdt = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fdt']));
    $cof = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['cof']));
    $fab1= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab1']));
    $fab2= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab2']));
    $fab3= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab3']));
    $non= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['non']));
    $dis= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['dis']));
    $comm= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comm']));
    $caad= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['caad']));
    $po= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['po']));
    $pod = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['pod']))));
    $dri = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['dri']))));

    $query = "UPDATE ncmr SET ab = '$ab', date = '$date', part = '$part', rev = '$rev' , partdesc = '$partdesc' , ncmrqty = '$ncmrqty' , comp = '$comp' , ncmrid = '$ncmrid' , rma = '$rma' , jno = '$jno' , fdt = '$fdt' , cof = '$cof' , fab1 = '$fab1' , fab2 = '$fab2' , fab3 = '$fab3' , non = '$non' , dis = '$dis' , comm = '$comm' , caad = '$caad' , po = '$po' , pod = '$pod' , dri = '$dri'  WHERE id = $id";

// echo your raw query and look for obvious errors
     echo "Query is : " . $query . "<br />";

// and at least use a basic mechanism to trap possibles errors
       mysqli_query($dbc, $query)  or die('Query Error : ' . mysqli_error($dbc));


// Confirm success with the user
        echo '<p>If you wish to edit more NCMRs, please <a href="list.php">go to the admin page!</a></p>';

        // echo your raw query and look for obvious errors
     echo "Query is : " . $query . "<br />";
// Clear the form data
    $id = "";
    $ab = "";
    $date = "";
    $part = "";
    $rev = "";
    $partdesc = "";
    $ncmrqty = "";
    $comp = "";
    $ncmrid = "";
    $rma = "";
    $jno = "";
    $fdt = "";
    $cof = "";
    $fab1= "";
    $fab2= "";
    $fab3= "";
    $non= "";
    $dis= "";
    $comm= "";
    $caad= "";
    $po= "";
    $pod = "";
    $dri = "";
            mysqli_close($dbc);
            }

  else {    

// Connect to the database
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
// Grab the profile data from the database
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '$id'";
  }
  else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '$id'";
  }

  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) { 
// The user row was found so display the user data
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>";
    echo '<fieldset>';

        echo '<div id="box1">';
            if (empty($row['ab'])) $row['ab'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['date'])) $row['date'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['part'])) $row['part'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['rev'])) $row['rev'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['partdesc'])) $row['partdesc'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['ncmrqty'])) $row['ncmrqty'] = "Empty";
            echo '<div id="ab"><span class="b">Added By:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ab" value="' . $row['ab'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="date"><span class="b">Date Filed:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="date" value="' . $row['date'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="part"><span class="b">Part Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="part" value="' . $row['part'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="rev"><span class="b">Part Revision:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rev" value="' . $row['rev'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="partdesc"><span class="b">Part Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="22">' . $row['partdesc'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="ncmrqty"><span class="b">NCMR Qty:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrqty" value="' . $row['ncmrqty'] . '" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';

//Company, Customer NCMR, Internal RMA, and Job Number
        echo '<div id="box2">';
            if (empty($row['comp'])) $row['comp'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['ncmrid'])) $row['ncmrid'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['rma'])) $row['rma'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['jno'])) $row['jno'] = "Empty";
                echo '<div id="comp"><span class="b">Company:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="comp" value="' . $row['comp'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="ncmrid"><span class="b">Customer NCMR ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrid" value="' . $row['ncmrid'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="rma"><span class="b">Internal RMA #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rma" value="' . $row['rma'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="jno"><span class="b">Job #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="jno" value="' . $row['jno'] . '" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';

//Type of Failure and Class of Failure
        echo '<div id="box3">';
            echo '<h2>Failure</h2>';
                echo '<div id="cof"><span class="b">Class of Failure:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="cof"  size="15" value="' . $row['cof'] . '" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="fdt"><span class="b">Failure Due To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="fdt"  size="15" value="' . $row['fdt'] . '" /></div>';

            echo '</div>';

//Fabricators
        echo '<div id="box4">';
            echo '<h2>Fabricators</h2>';
if ($row['fab1']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}


if ($row['fab2']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab2">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab2'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab2"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
if ($row['fab3']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab3">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab3'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab3"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}       echo '</div>';

//Nonconformity, Disposition, Comments and Comments & Additional Details
        echo '<div id="box5">';
            if (empty($row['non'])) $row['non'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['dis'])) $row['dis'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['comm'])) $row['comm'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['caad'])) $row['caad'] = "Empty";

            echo '<div id="non"><span class="b">Nonconformity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['non'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="dis"><span class="b">Disposition:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['dis'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="comm"><span class="b">Comments:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['comm'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="caad"><span class="b">Comments and/or Additional Details:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['caad'] . '</textarea></div>';

                echo '<div id="podr">';
                        if (empty($row['po'])) $row['po'] ="Empty";
                        if (empty($row['pod'])) $row['pod'] ="Empty";
                        if (empty($row['dir'])) $row['dri'] ="Empty";

                    echo '<div id="po"><span class="b">PO:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="po"  size="7" value="' . $row['po'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="pod"><span class="b">PO Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="pod"  size="7" value="' . $row['pod'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="dri"><span class="b">Date Received:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="dri"  size="7" value="' . $row['dri'] . '" /></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="button2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Edits" name="submit" /></div>';
//Save ID so it can be used with POST request.
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$id' name='id'/>"; 

        echo '</div>';
    echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
        }
    }

echo '</div>';

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING** your code is suseptible to sql injection attacks in your `where` clause!

Comment: @DanielA.White It's nice that you warn the OP of possible SQL injection, but you don't give any directions as to solving this issue. Perhaps you could add a link or something for the OP to read and learn?

Comment: Directions can be found in my answer, in addition to the solution for the original problem! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use concatenation operator `.` before and after `$_GET['id']` thingie. Or embed it into string:

```
    ".... WHERE id = {$_GET['id']}";
```

(note, that your `$_GET['id']` is not sanitized and taken directly from the network input. not the best thing to do).

Answer (score 3):

Your forget concatenation operators here: `"$_GET['id']""`, should be `".$_GET['id'].";"`

Each time you see a **Parse error: syntax error**, the fault is on your side. You have the filename and the line number, you just have to look :-)

Comment: As the whole code is here, I presum there is no other SQL condition, so the ; can be added safely (it's just cleaner).

Comment: *nod* Its more that I think that the `;` there in the original was the end of statement `;` rather than part of the string. I personally don't think adding in the ; makes it cleaner but that is personal preference.

Comment: @Damien don't you mean it should be `".$_GET['id']."";`? Thanks for the direction though it got me going in the right direction.  I've just updated the code, with a new problem now.

Comment: IMO, it should be ".$_GET['id'].";"; OR ".$_GET['id'];

Answer (score 2):

You have misquoted `$_GET['id']` at the end:

```
WHERE id = "$_GET['id']"
// should be
WHERE id = '{$_GET['id']}'
```

However you should first escape it with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
// Then use
WHERE id = '$id'
```

Comment: Why does everyone miss that?  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['id'])); First line in the sanitation script.

Comment: @MattRidge I see it is there, but you're still using `$_GET['id']` directly in your query.

Comment: @MattRidge What stands out to us is not the big block of escaped variables, but the one single one in the SQL string that is unescaped.

Comment: I changed it, sorry I meant to update it on the original page, but the post still is not going through with the ID.

Comment: @MattRidge All your other values are from `$_POST` is the id  really from `$_GET`, as though it was directly passed in the form action?

Comment: What do you mean? I could use POST, but I was told to make it as GET... because originally this info is sent to this page.

Comment: @MattRidge If the id comes from the same form as the rest of the values, it should be POST. However, if the form was like `<form method='post' action='yourscript.php?id=12345'>` then it is correct to use GET for only the id.

Comment: I think this is where I am getting confused.  What should I be doing? The data is being called from a table of a database originally... should it be GET or POST?

Comment: @MattRidge I think it should be `$_POST['id']` from the looks of the rest of your code. There's a `<input type='hidden' name='id'>` in there populating the `$_POST['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

My memory of php is getting fuzzy but this part looks wrong:

```
WHERE id = "$_GET['id']"";
```

I assume you are using double quotes there to prevent confusion with the single quotes in your variable but I would imagine you would want some kind of concatenation operator there. ie:

```
WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
```

Alternatively you could just do

```
$getid = $_GET['id']
```

before hand and use the simpler variable name in your expression. This would be more consistent with how you deal with the rest of the variables...

Answer (score 0):

Escape getting the `id` off the querystring like you did for the other values. It isn't concatinating properly.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the operator `.` for string concatenation. This is how it should look:

```
$query = "UPDATE ncmr SET ab = '$ab', date = '$date', part = '$part', rev = '$rev' , partdesc = '$partdesc' , ncmrqty = '$ncmrqty' , comp = '$comp' , ncmrid = '$ncmrid' , rma = '$rma' , jno = '$jno' , fdt = '$fdt' , cof = '$cof' , fab1 = '$fab1' , fab2 = '$fab2' , fab3 = '$fab3' , non = '$non' , dis = '$dis' , comm = '$comm' , caad = '$caad' , po = '$po' , pod = '$pod' , dri = '$dri'  WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
```

And, very important: Never use unverified request data in SQL queries or you will be vulnerable to [MySQL injections](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)! in this case, if the id is always an integer, adding (int) before `$_GET['id']` will help:

```
$query = "UPDATE ncmr SET ab = '$ab', date = '$date', part = '$part', rev = '$rev' , partdesc = '$partdesc' , ncmrqty = '$ncmrqty' , comp = '$comp' , ncmrid = '$ncmrid' , rma = '$rma' , jno = '$jno' , fdt = '$fdt' , cof = '$cof' , fab1 = '$fab1' , fab2 = '$fab2' , fab3 = '$fab3' , non = '$non' , dis = '$dis' , comm = '$comm' , caad = '$caad' , po = '$po' , pod = '$pod' , dri = '$dri'  WHERE id = ".(int)$_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of work, switching code around and sleepless nights I seem to of answered my own question with help here, and I gave kudos to those who did give answers that pointed me in the right direction.

Here is what I did, from the original code I changed these bits:

Lines 20 through 28: I put the accessing the database before the script, don't ask me why I didn't see this before, but I did it, a beginners mistake I am sure, but still it happens especially since I am still a beginnier.

This is the code between lines 20-28 as it looks now.

```
// Connect to the database
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

      $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(0));
      if(isset($_GET['id']))
         $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['id']));

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST["id"]));
```

Line 54 was rewritten as suggested here.

It now is has the correct amount of quote marks on the end of it, and looks like this.

```
$query = "UPDATE ncmr SET ab = '$ab', date = '$date', part = '$part', rev = '$rev' , partdesc = '$partdesc' , ncmrqty = '$ncmrqty' , comp = '$comp' , ncmrid = '$ncmrid' , rma = '$rma' , jno = '$jno' , fdt = '$fdt' , cof = '$cof' , fab1 = '$fab1' , fab2 = '$fab2' , fab3 = '$fab3' , non = '$non' , dis = '$dis' , comm = '$comm' , caad = '$caad' , po = '$po' , pod = '$pod' , dri = '$dri'  WHERE id = '$id'";[/code]
```

I removed line 67.

This one:

```
 echo "Query is : " . $query . "<br />";
```

I removed line 97 and 98.

```
// Connect to the database
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

That is all the edits.

Here is the complete code.

```
<?php
require_once('connectvars.php');
echo '<div id="postwrap">'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Edit</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/postie.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div id="logo">
    <img src="../images/PDI_Logo_2.1.gif" alt="PDI Logo" />
</div>

<?php
// Connect to the database
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

      $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(0));
      if(isset($_GET['id']))
         $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['id']));

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST["id"]));

// Enter data into the database
    $ab = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ab']));
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['date']))));
    $part = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['part']));
    $rev = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rev']));
    $partdesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['partdesc']));
    $ncmrqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrqty']));
    $comp = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comp']));
    $ncmrid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrid']));
    $rma = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rma']));
    $jno = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['jno']));
    $fdt = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fdt']));
    $cof = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['cof']));
    $fab1= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab1']));
    $fab2= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab2']));
    $fab3= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab3']));
    $non= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['non']));
    $dis= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['dis']));
    $comm= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comm']));
    $caad= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['caad']));
    $po= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['po']));
    $pod = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['pod']))));
    $dri = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['dri']))));

    $query = "UPDATE ncmr SET ab = '$ab', date = '$date', part = '$part', rev = '$rev' , partdesc = '$partdesc' , ncmrqty = '$ncmrqty' , comp = '$comp' , ncmrid = '$ncmrid' , rma = '$rma' , jno = '$jno' , fdt = '$fdt' , cof = '$cof' , fab1 = '$fab1' , fab2 = '$fab2' , fab3 = '$fab3' , non = '$non' , dis = '$dis' , comm = '$comm' , caad = '$caad' , po = '$po' , pod = '$pod' , dri = '$dri'  WHERE id = '$id'";

// echo your raw query and look for obvious errors
     echo "Query is : " . $query . "<br />";

// and at least use a basic mechanism to trap possibles errors
       mysqli_query($dbc, $query)  or die('Query Error : ' . mysqli_error($dbc));


// Confirm success with the user
        echo '<p>If you wish to edit more NCMRs, please <a href="list.php">go to the admin page!</a></p>';

// Clear the form data
    $id = "";
    $ab = "";
    $date = "";
    $part = "";
    $rev = "";
    $partdesc = "";
    $ncmrqty = "";
    $comp = "";
    $ncmrid = "";
    $rma = "";
    $jno = "";
    $fdt = "";
    $cof = "";
    $fab1= "";
    $fab2= "";
    $fab3= "";
    $non= "";
    $dis= "";
    $comm= "";
    $caad= "";
    $po= "";
    $pod = "";
    $dri = "";
            mysqli_close($dbc);
            }

  else {    

// Grab the profile data from the database
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '$id'";
  }
  else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '$id'";
  }

  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) { 
// The user row was found so display the user data
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>";
    echo '<fieldset>';

        echo '<div id="box1">';
            if (empty($row['ab'])) $row['ab'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['date'])) $row['date'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['part'])) $row['part'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['rev'])) $row['rev'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['partdesc'])) $row['partdesc'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['ncmrqty'])) $row['ncmrqty'] = "Empty";
            echo '<div id="ab"><span class="b">Added By:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ab" value="' . $row['ab'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="date"><span class="b">Date Filed:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="date" value="' . $row['date'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="part"><span class="b">Part Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="part" value="' . $row['part'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="rev"><span class="b">Part Revision:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rev" value="' . $row['rev'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="partdesc"><span class="b">Part Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="22">' . $row['partdesc'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="ncmrqty"><span class="b">NCMR Qty:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrqty" value="' . $row['ncmrqty'] . '" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';

//Company, Customer NCMR, Internal RMA, and Job Number
        echo '<div id="box2">';
            if (empty($row['comp'])) $row['comp'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['ncmrid'])) $row['ncmrid'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['rma'])) $row['rma'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['jno'])) $row['jno'] = "Empty";
                echo '<div id="comp"><span class="b">Company:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="comp" value="' . $row['comp'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="ncmrid"><span class="b">Customer NCMR ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrid" value="' . $row['ncmrid'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="rma"><span class="b">Internal RMA #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rma" value="' . $row['rma'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="jno"><span class="b">Job #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="jno" value="' . $row['jno'] . '" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';

//Type of Failure and Class of Failure
        echo '<div id="box3">';
            echo '<h2>Failure</h2>';
                echo '<div id="cof"><span class="b">Class of Failure:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="cof"  size="15" value="' . $row['cof'] . '" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="fdt"><span class="b">Failure Due To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="fdt"  size="15" value="' . $row['fdt'] . '" /></div>';

            echo '</div>';

//Fabricators
        echo '<div id="box4">';
            echo '<h2>Fabricators</h2>';
if ($row['fab1']=="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}


if ($row['fab2']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab2">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab2'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab2"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
if ($row['fab3']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab3">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab3'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab3"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}       echo '</div>';

//Nonconformity, Disposition, Comments and Comments & Additional Details
        echo '<div id="box5">';
            if (empty($row['non'])) $row['non'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['dis'])) $row['dis'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['comm'])) $row['comm'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['caad'])) $row['caad'] = "Empty";

            echo '<div id="non"><span class="b">Nonconformity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['non'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="dis"><span class="b">Disposition:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['dis'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="comm"><span class="b">Comments:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['comm'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="caad"><span class="b">Comments and/or Additional Details:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['caad'] . '</textarea></div>';

                echo '<div id="podr">';
                        if (empty($row['po'])) $row['po'] ="Empty";
                        if (empty($row['pod'])) $row['pod'] ="Empty";
                        if (empty($row['dir'])) $row['dri'] ="Empty";

                    echo '<div id="po"><span class="b">PO:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="po"  size="7" value="' . $row['po'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="pod"><span class="b">PO Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="pod"  size="7" value="' . $row['pod'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="dri"><span class="b">Date Received:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="dri"  size="7" value="' . $row['dri'] . '" /></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="button2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Edits" name="submit" /></div>';
//Save ID so it can be used with POST request.
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$id' name='id'/>"; 

        echo '</div>';
    echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
        }
    }

echo '</div>';

?>
</body>
</html>
```